# Nested if..else... breaking parental flow?

Tags: php

I'm running through a few scenarios with some IFs and I'm running into something that defies my logic/understanding.

Yes, I'm very low-level with programming, so maybe I'm royally screwing up something very rudimentary.

Anyway, I have something like so:

```
if(condition==1) {
  if(conditionA==2) {
    // SAY I LOVE YOU
  } else {
    // SAY HEY BABY
  }
}

if(condition2==1) {
  if(conditionAA==2) {
    // SAY I LOVE YOU
  } else {
    // SAY HEY BABY
  }
}
```

Now, when condition1 and condition2 are both equal to 1 and conditionA and conditionAA do NOT equal 2, the else statements are fine.  However, when conditionA or conditionAA DO equal 2, the whole scenario breaks at that very spot.

For example, conditionA DOES NOT equal 2, the else fires and if conditionAA IS equal to 2 ,stuff breaks there.  If conditionA DID equal 2, the whole thing breaks right there.

I don't understand why :(

Thanks in advance.  Your advice will help me to restructure this mess.

Comment: Cleanly formatted tabs in source will make it easier to read the control flow.

Comment: What do you mean by it 'breaks'? Tell what you're getting and what you expect.

Comment: Please explain "stuff breaks there". What exactly is breaking? Is it not performing the "SAY I LOVE YOU" statement? Are you sure the "SAY I LOVE YOU" isn't what's causing the problem instead?

Comment: Post the actual code that is causing problems. Perhaps you only have a single equal sign somewhere, etc...

Comment: I don't really get it. If you don't get the expected behaviour then change your if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry... it was a bit of badness in the nested "IF".  I was reestablishing a variable each time the nested "IF" was fired, making the original variable unavailable to later large scale evaluations.

I need to get more function/class savvy to get all this junk off of one page.

Thanks for jogging my mind, gang.